# Heat spreaders on electric elements

Tags: equipment

I use electric kettle and hlt, the issue I keep having is that the brews keep coming out darker than I want. This went unnoticed when brewing stouts and bitters, but I have tried a couple of very pale summer ales and a light pilsner, all of which came out a touch too dark.

I have been scratching my head and I was wondering if it is the concentrated heat of the elements caramlising the sugars?

Then if a heat spreader on the element would help, and if it would how would I go about making one?

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix may be to change your element to one with a lower watt density, such as Camco 02965. It has a density of 50W/8.5W per square inch/cm.  These elements are longer than regular (HWD) heating elements and so spread the heat over a larger area.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (with big batches of sauce, not beer) and used a 1/4" copper plate larger than the element to disperse the heat. Worked very well, but wasn't cheap. Aluminum plate might work nearly as well, and would be a lot cheaper.